# python: shape mismatch when adding an item to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Im using matplotlib to plot a graph out of a dictionary with strings and ints, when i plot the graph with its initial values it works, but if i add another key to the dictionary
lets say for example

`ADD,example,example.com,20.0`

it gives the following error, when i PLOT the graph again

```
"ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"
```

but this issue only happens with this graph, whenever i use a pie graph, i am able to add items to the dictionary, and successfully plot the pie graph again.

Can someone with more experience than me show me what i am doing wrong?

here is the relevant part of my code for this issue
Thank you for your time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
empresas = { "Prodsmart": ["prodsmart.com",1.5],"James": ["james.finance",3.9],
            "Talkdesk": ["talkdesk.com",24.5], "Codacy": ["codacy.com",6.7],
            "Veniam": ["veniam.com", 26.9], "Sensei": ["sensei.tech",0.5]}


def add_empresa(info):
    empresas[info[0]] = [info[1],float(info[2])]

nlist = []
for x, k in empresas.items():
    nlist.append(k[1]) 

def graph1():
    group_data = nlist
    group_names = list(empresas.keys())
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.barh(group_names, group_data)
    plt.show()
    return        

inputs = ""
while inputs != "EXIT":
    inputs = input("insert a command:" )
    inputzs = inputs.split(",")
    if inputzs[0] == "ADD" and len(inputzs) == 4:
        add_empresa(inputzs[1:])        
    elif inputzs[0] == "PLOT":
        graph1()
```

Comment: You need to create `nlist` in `graph1` as well, otherwise `group_data` will be shorter than `group_names` after adding a new item to the dictionary. Also, extract key and value at the same time, you cannot rely on that a dictionary stays ordered for Python versions older than 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nlist` (and hence `group_data`) is created once before the while loop. So as soon as you add a new item to the dictionary in your while-loop, `empresas` will have more elements than `nlist`, and hence `group_names` will be longer than `group-data` in your call to `graph1`.

To fix this, extract the values for `group_data` in the call to `graph1`:

```
def graph1():
    gen = ((k, v[1]) for k, v in empresas.items())
    group_names, group_data = zip(*gen)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.barh(group_names, group_data)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: created `nlist` in `graph1` like you suggested in your previous comment and it worked, thank you. Also, is it necessary to extract the values from `group_data` like you suggested? since just creating `nlist = []
for x, k in empresas.items():
    nlist.append(k[1]) ` solved it

Comment: As long as you do not add elements to the dict, iterating over the keys or values should result in the same order. I do not know whether this is guaranteed, though.